# How to install POP3 and SMTP in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, smtp, pop3

I have Postfix installed on an Ubuntu box, but now I need to configure POP3 and SMTP. Is there some guide on how to do this?

Comment: @TiZon, this is a Server related question...

Comment: Off topic because Postfix just doesn't do POP3...

Comment: And Postfix already **is** the SMTP server/client.

Comment: @André: I only edited a grammatical mistake in your question and removed the "Thanks" as per the community guidelines. Nothing to do with the closing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POP3 is not part of postfix. Postfix is an MTA.
I suggest you use dovecot as the pop3 server.

There are plenty of guides on the internet

http://rimuhosting.com/support/settingupemail.jsp?mta=postfix
http://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL